# Tensorflow dataset generator error in channel dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mask

I am trying to train my model for image segmentation task and for that i am using a generator to yield the dataset. i have trained it multiple times before but recently I am facing this error.

```
ValueError:'generator' yielded an element of shape (128,192,3) where an element of shape (128,192,1) was expected.
```

when i printed out the shapes of my image and mask that comes out of generator it shows.

```
image:(128,192,1)
mask:(128,192,3)
```

The generator element gets both the image and mask data loaded from  the tensorflow dataset. The question is how does the shape of the mask of an grayscale image changes to 3 when even the input image is grayscale of 1?
How to possibly convert the mask back to channel of 1?

Unfortunately I cannot post the complete code to reproduce as its under privacy

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more of the library you're using for reading the image it's hard to know. I am assuming you're using PIL and I'll do

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('im1.jpg','r')
img = img.convert('L')
```

'L' is for the grayscale, you can check more mode -> https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html

While you're updating your code, you should check the preprocessing module of keras, then the code will be

```
# Returns a PIL image
image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_path, color_mode="grayscale")
 
input_arr = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
input_arr = np.array([input_arr])  # Convert single image to a batch.
predictions = model.predict(input_arr)
```

More information -> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using opencv to read images. I kind of solved the problem by loading the masks with [:,:,:1] from the dataset dictionary. But still cant figure out why mask shape alone has changed eventhough  i had a precheck of loading the masks and images into grayscale if it is not already a grayscale.

Comment: Without more of the code it's hard to guess, maybe a, incorrect shape when you convert from opencv image to a tensor.

Comment: If you have the time I recommend you to try the tf.keras.preprocessing.image module, it will deal with that for you and you can see other useful functions for augmenting your images

Comment: okay. But rightnow i use a preporcessing pipeline directly into my model and there has to be something inside it. Yeah i will also look into Keras preprocessing